# Arduino Uno - Analog Circuit Simulator

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware, simulator, analog-sampling, op-amp

I control an analog circuit with Arduino Uno. I want to simulate an Arduino Uno with operational amplifiers (741). Can I simulate Arduino with SPICE?

Comment: No, there is no SPICE model for an Arduino. But then given that an ATMega328 doesn't have any DAC capabilities you would only need to feed in a digital stimulus to your simulation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the one which is closest to be useful for your question

**Link**: https://markmegarry.github.io/AVR8js-Falstad/

Try it out for yourself
It is very slow though.
[image: Simulator Arduino and SPICE!]

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngspice.
From what is written there, the Xspice part could be used for creating a simple model of the Arduino, for checking how the analog part of your circuit interacts with the uC.
Unfortunately the main site () is down, atm, as many other projects hosted on SourceForge. But it might be worth having a look, once it's back online.